# aggregate metrics regarding akka streams

Tags: scala, stream, akka, metrics

In my app, I have a source which I'm multiplexing for client calls.

Something like:

```
val source: RunnableGraph[Source[...]] = ...

def foo() = source.run().log("sending user something").map(...)
```

If I have 1000s of the client calling foo and foo ticks every second there will be millions of pointless log messages. So I want to get rid of the individual log above and replace it with one aggregate message something like:

"sent something to X clients".

I've looked at Kamon and cinnamon, so I appreciate it is probably possible to do with those but ideally there's something far more lightweight for something like this?

Comment: https://kamon.io , hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible if you will be aggregating your data in small windows like this https://softwaremill.com/windowing-data-in-akka-streams/
Or you can have Map[ClientId, Monoid[YourCallMetrics]] and combine it though the runnable graph

Comment: thanks @mikhail. I like less the windowing idea because it takes it out of context, which is source ticked with id=XXX, as a result, downstream subscribers ticked. I want to be able to log one message saying "<n> clients got update XXX". If there was a way to mark the beginning and end of downstream, then I could reset a counter before first subscriber is notified and log the count after last subscriber is notified. Does it make sense?